# Returning response from an imported function in Node.Js and Express.Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nodemailer

I have an express.js post method in which I am calling a function whose code is below:

```
    module.exports.sendEmail = function(to,subject,message){
        var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
          service : 'gmail',
          auth:{
            user : "",
            pass : ""
          }
        });
        var mailOptions = {
          from:'findadriver9@gmail.com',
          to: to,
          subject:subject,
          html:message
        };
        return transporter.sendMail(mailOptions).then(function(data){
          var result ={
            success:true,
            message:"Email Sent"
          }
          return result;
        }).catch(function(err){
          var err={
            success:false
          };
      return err;
    });
   }
```

How do I call the function such that depending on the success and failure I can define the response?

```
var response = sendEmail.sendEmail(req.body.empemail,subject,details);
res.send(response);
```

I tried that above way, but I am not getting any response due to asynchronous nature of Node.js.

Comment: Well `sendEmail.sendEmail(...).then(result => res.json(result));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make changes into your sendEmail function,add one extra argument as callback function as bellow

```
module.exports.sendEmail = function(to,subject,message,cb){
    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      service : 'gmail',
      auth:{
        user : 'demo.user@mail.com',
        pass : 'demo#password'
      }
    });
    var mailOptions = {
      from:'demo.user@mail.com',
      to: to,
      subject:subject,
      html:message
    };
    return transporter.sendMail(mailOptions).then(function(data){
      var result ={
        success:true,
        message:"Email Sent"
      }
      cb(result);
    }).catch(function(err){
      var err={
        success:false
      };
  cb(err);
});
}
```

Here, this function will not return any result but after complition of work it will send result to callback function.

Now call this function as bellow

```
  sendEmail.sendEmail(req.body.empemail,subject,details,function(result){
   res.send(result);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to *await* the email being sent:

```
app.post("/mail", async function(req,res){
  const response = await sendEmail.sendEmail(req.body.empemail,subject,details);
  //do whatever
  res.send(response);
});
```

Doing the same with good (old) promises only:

```
app.post("/", function(req, res){
 sendEmail
   .sendEmail(req.body.empemail,subject,details)
   .then(function(response){
      //do whatever
      res.send(response);
   });
});
```